# Proper form of a regex in SELECT of an Access ComboBox

Tags: sql, regex, ms-access

I have a ComboBox which takes it's source from a query. One of the query' fields is a number like H-1234=AAA-0382 or HN903=BBB-94522 (Field is `ID Symix`, Table is `DessinSelonProjet_Choix`).

In the combobox, I want to display this number, but not the part before the = sign in both cases. I wanted to use a `Mid(number, position of = sign)`. In SQL I researched that the position function is CHARINDEX, but I did not manage to get it working. 
 Here is the code when showing the whole thing:

```
SELECT DessinSelonProjet_Choix.[ID Symix], DessinSelonProjet_Choix.[Numéro Document], 
DessinSelonProjet_Choix.Description, DessinSelonProjet_Choix.[Groupe Source]
FROM DessinSelonProjet_Choix
ORDER BY DessinSelonProjet_Choix.[ID Symix];
```

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT Mid(DessinSelonProjet_Choix.[ID Symix],CHARINDEX('=', 
DessinSelonProjet_Choix.[ID Symix]) AS [Location]) AS Expr1, 
DessinSelonProjet_Choix.[Numéro Document], 
DessinSelonProjet_Choix.Description, DessinSelonProjet_Choix.[Groupe Source]
FROM DessinSelonProjet_Choix
ORDER BY DessinSelonProjet_Choix.[ID Symix];
```

> Syntax error (missing operator) in the expression Mid(DessinSelonProjet_Choix.[ID Symix],CHARINDEX('=', DessinSelonProjet_Choix.[ID Symix]) AS [Location]) AS Expr1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
Mid([ID Symix], INSTR('=', [ID Symix])+1, len([ID Symix])-INSTR('=', [ID Symix])) AS Expr1,
[Numéro Document],   
Description, 
[Groupe Source]
FROM DessinSelonProjet_Choix
ORDER BY [ID Symix];
```

The statement you had was using an `alias` within a function. Also, you have to use `len` to get all characters after `=` in your string.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I get : Undefined function CHARINDEX

Comment: there is no `charindex` in access. changed it to `instr`.

Comment: Ah... of course. No error now but it doesn't remove anything at all... which is weird. I can't see a flaw.

Comment: changed the last argument to `instr`. please try again.

Comment: I ended up using something completely different. However I believe your solution would have worked.